# The Kendo ui Scheduler does not render correctly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

The Kendo ui Scheduler does not render correctly unless the containing element is visible at initialization time.

If you call .kendoScheduler() on an element that is not "on screen" (e.g. display: none) it does not render and function correctly.

In particular the height, scrollbars and time bar properties do not result in expected functionality. But if element start visible the problem does not appear

[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/927UW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Scheduler uses JavaScript size calculations and these do not work for hidden elements.

To readjust the widget layout, execute the resize() method of the Scheduler after it becomes visible.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/using-kendo-in-responsive-web-pages#individual-widget-resizing

Comment: Just resize does not work......Because the information also does not show. 

A similar problem is that of kendo Grid, but the offered solution did not solve my problem because this scheduler within a directive of the angular.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-grid-does-not-render-correctly-unless-the-containing-element-is-visible-at-initialization-time